clickhouse ERROR: column "date" does not exist
I created external tables in clickhouse that pull up from postgres, but 1 of the tables gives an error type: pqxx::undefined_column, e.what()= ERROR: column "date" does not exist
This column is present in the postgres. What is the problem?
I tried to enclose the field in double quotes when creating it, but it doesn't help

try backticks for column name but provide full example
